# floating numbers next to textboxes, doesn't display correctly

Tags: html, css

I have 3 simple textareas, with numbers next to them. I used a CSS table before to display them, but I need to later add things in between each row so that isn't efficient.

For some reason, the 2nd number, "2)" goes up next to the 1). I can't understand why this is happening.

**JSFIDDLE:** http://jsfiddle.net/b5h7p/

**HTML:**

```
<div style="float:left;">1)</div>
<div style="width:90%; float:right;">
    <input type="textarea" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div style="float:left;">2)</div>
<div style="width:90%; float:right;">
    <input type="textarea" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div style="float:left;">3)</div>
<div style="width:90%; float:right;">
    <input type="textarea" style="width:100%;">
</div>
```

Comment: You need `clear:both`

Comment: Can you tell me where I need it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set floating divs with `clear`

**Markup**

```
<div style="float:left;">1)</div>
<div style="width:90%; float:right;">
    <input type="textarea" style="width:100%;">
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/b5h7p/1/)

- [Clear Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clear)
- [Float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)